# C#: Writing file to Excel issue

Tags: c#, excel, closedxml

I am using ClosedXML to write my data into Excel. But here is the problem. When I write my data the old data gets removed and saves only data which I am calling. I know that is because of "new" and "Add" word I am using. Is there any other way I can specify to write files?

```
var workbook = new XLWorkbook();
var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.Add("Common");
worksheet.Cell(2, 1).Value = "Sent";
workbook.SaveAs(@"..\..\File.xlsx");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: This should work

```
string pathfile = @"..\..\File.xlsx";
XLWorkbook workbook = new XLWorkbook(pathfile);
IXLWorksheet worksheet = workbook.Worksheet("Common");
worksheet.Cell(2, 1).Value = "Sent";
workbook.Save();
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to instantiate

```
var workbook = new XLWorkbook()
```

in global scope and then append to it in whatever method you're using.